# Call to reloadRowsAtIndexPaths breaks the setImageWithURLRequest

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, afnetworking-2, sizetofit

I have the problem with image loaded to the header cell, the problem was that requested image was not loaded (displayed as it turns out) and only the image loaded on view load was used.

I have narrowed the problem - I'm calling `sizeToFit` to resize label and then if the size is greater then minimum cell size I'm notifying `delegate` that I need new size of the cell. The delegate function calls `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on the cell that was requesting resize. The `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called which is using new size.

I need this behaviour though as the cell needs to grow/shrink to accommodate the amount of text.

Has anyone faced similar issue, and most importantly has anyone got any workaround?

This is a [sample project](http://greladesign.com/battlefield/restricted/so/setimagewithurlrequest-loads-with-success-but-the-same-image-is-displayed/Test%20ImageRowCell.zip) that shows this issue, if you go to the `CSTitleCell` and method `resize` to comment-out the `delegate` call you will see that it starts to work (but not resizing of the cell). Change of the content is done through swipe left/right.